# How to fix 'there are no arguments to 'glGenVertexArrays' that depend on a template parameter ...' error in c++

Tags: c++, templates, opengl, glfw

I have a template class with multiple unsigned int's a `T*` and 5 function and only one of them is declared, the class is created in a .h file and in the end it includes a .tcc file where the remaing 4 functions will be declared, in the `GenerateBuffer` function i use multiple OpenGL calls and all of them giving the same Error `there are no arguments to ‘glGenVertexArrays’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘glGenVertexArrays’ must be available`

I used to have the functions declarations in a .cpp file and instead of including in the end of the .h file the .cpp file included the .h file in the beginning, it didn't give any errors but when trying to call functions it would give a undeclared linking error, currently i have this

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

in the header file, i tried to also put it in the beining of the .tcc file but i get the same error, tried in both same error. The only solutions that i found for this error online is include the files in question,but i always had, or to add `using namespace` but glGenVertexArrays isnt part of any namespace nor is my class

***Header File***

```
#ifndef _VERTEXBUFFER_
#define _VERTEXBUFFER_

#include "../Core/Settings.h"

template<typename T> class VertexBuffer {

public:
    unsigned int BufferId;
    unsigned int IndexId;
    unsigned int VAO;

    T* Vertices;
    unsigned int* Indexs;

    int DrawCount() { return (Indexs != nullptr) ? sizeof(Indexs) / sizeof(Indexs[0]) : sizeof(Vertices) / sizeof(Vertices[0]);}

    void GenerateBuffer(T data[]);
    void SetIndexData(unsigned int data[]);
    void Bind();
    void UnBind();
};

#include "VertexBuffer.tcc"

#endif
```

***Function in question***

```
template<typename T> void VertexBuffer<T>::GenerateBuffer(T data[]) {

    Vertices = data;

    if (Settings::Engine == OpenGL) {

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &BufferId);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(data[0]), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all what is unclear on the error message *"there are no arguments to ‘glGenVertexArrays’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘glGenVertexArrays’ must be available"*? You've to include the OpenGL header files before this part of the code. If you don't want to do that than create another method without template arguments and move this part of the code to the method, since it doesn't depend on any template argument and call the new method.

Comment: @Rabbid76 like i said i have tried including before the code but the error persists and i know that what i have included is correct because in another files it works

Comment: `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` doesn't include the OpenGL declarations

Comment: @Rabbid76 then what should i do? i can use the same exact same functions in other files with only `#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` without any problems

Comment: `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` is not related to `glfw3.h`. What about `gl.h` / `glext.h`. Or do you use *glew* or *glad*?

Comment: @Rabbid76 same error, i added `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` because when i started testing openGl functions like `glBindBuffer` didn't appear until i added `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES`

Comment: It would be better to scrap your `VertexBuffer` class. There are just too many things wrong with it. Buffer objects don't need VAOs, so there's no reason to have one in such a class. There doesn't need to be such a direct connection between vertex data and index data (and there's no reason both sets of data couldn't go into the same buffer). And most important of all, vertex buffers don't need to be specific to a particular `T`; there is every reason to store multiple types of data in a buffer object.

Comment: @pekira "same error, i added `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` because when i started testing openGl functions like `glBindBuffer` didn't appear until i added `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES`" You're asking for trouble here. You really should put some thoughts about proper OpenGL loading, and the error message you're getting is very related to that.

Answer (score 2):

Mildly unrelated to your actual question, but IMHO too important to just be put in a comment: You're using the `sizeof` operator in an naive way:

> ```
> template<typename T>
> void VertexBuffer<T>::GenerateBuffer(T data[])
> {
>         glBufferData(…, sizeof(data), …, …);
> ```

It doesn't work that way. You see, `sizeof` returns the size of the result of the expression you pass into it. It's just as valid to write `sizeof(1+2)`. So what is the size of `data`? Well the size of the result of expression `data` of course. Given that *data* is an array function parameter (and not an actual array object) the expresion `data` decays into a pointer and hence `sizeof(data)` tells you the size of a pointer, not the size of the array!

I'm just pointing that out here, because once you've fixed that original problem, you'll undoubtedly fall over this one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, about the original problem i am not able to resolve wet so i kinda bypass the problem by adding the arguments `-fpermissive` now the errors are just warning and it works perfectly